# Is it possible use css sibling functionality with complex selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to target an adjacent sibling but only if the first sibling has a particular descendant class.

This is different from "[Is there a previous sibling selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)" In this question I'm asking how to target the *adjacent* sibling. In that question they are asking how to target the *previous* sibling.

What makes this question different from basic sibling functionality is that I want the selector to only apply IF the previous sibling has a certain descendant class nested in it.

I have a dynamic web site where a particular html page may display in one of two ways (see code block below).

I want to write a css selector that will target the section tag, but only when the *previous div* has "george" as a descendant class.

Page 1

```html
<div>
  <p class="joan">
  </p>
</div>
<section>
</section>
```

Page 2

```html
<div>
  <p class="george">
  </p>
</div>
<section>
</section>
```

my css that **does not work**:

```css
div .george + section {
}
```

Is there a way to do this with css only? Or do I have to resort to javascript?

I know this would be simple to do if I restructured the html so that `<section>` was nested inside `<div>`. This is not the answer that I am looking for because the html structure of the page is not changeable.

Comment: No CSS only way currently

Comment: Didn't try it, you it might be doable using xpath.

Comment: As @j08691 says, not with CSS. See my answer to the linked question for some exposition on this topic.

Comment: @BoltClock returns!

Comment: @j08691: :) I've had some catching up to do...